# Queue/Waiting List position calculator

Tags: algorithm

Language not really important for this, I will translate to C#, but I am after a queue or waiting list position algorithm.

So I have effectively three queues in a store, Staff 1, Staff 2, Staff 3.

People in the queue can choose to book with an individual staff member or first available. So the queue would look something like.

1. Staff 1
2. Staff 3
3. First Available
4. Staff 3
5. First Available
6. Staff 2
7. First Available
8. Staff 1
9. First Available
10. Staff 3

So for the next person who comes into the store how would I calculate their queue position if they selected
a) A staff member (1,2 or 3)
b) First available

Comment: What is the probability distribution for the duration of serving a client (excluding the waiting time in the queue)?

Comment: Assume all services are the same length.

Comment: OK. May we then also assume that their is a clock tick at which all desks can take in the next client simultaneously? Or are the service desks not synchronised in that way?

Comment: Yes, they could take them all simultaneously.

Comment: Let me know if I got the question right, what I understand is: there are 3 queues in which a customer can wait for: `staff1, staff2, staff3` before he/she gets serviced. A customer can explicitly specify in which queue he/she might want to go or wait for the first available slot in any of the queue i.e `First Available`.

Comment: and that you want to know how many persons are there in a waiting line before he/she can be serviced

Comment: Should the entries  that you gave as example be processed in order, without regard of which clients may book after them? I mean, if someone chooses "First Available", and there will be 2 desks that will free up at the same time, should there be a preference for one of the desks based on the preferences of the client that come after them, so that they will be served as fast as possible? Or should the selection only be made by the information of the clients that booked *before* them?

Comment: Are you there??

Answer (score 0):

Given that at each passing of a constant interval each of the staff-linked queues gets 1 entry shorter simultaneously, we can reflect the waiting time for a new client as follows:

- If the client wishes to be served by a specific member of staff, the waiting time (or rank) corresponds to the length of the queue that is linked with that particular member of staff
- If the client wishes to be served by the desk that becomes first available, then this means they should be added to the shortest staff-linked queue, and so their staff selection can be made immediately, and the waiting time is thus determined accordingly as in the previous point.

If you have 3 staff members, then you would need to implement this with three (FIFO) queues. Put clients in the queue according to above considerations. It is easy to report the length of that queue, which is the rank for that client: 0 means they get served when the next interval starts.

At each passing of the fixed interval, you would pull one entry from each of the queues, which represent the clients that are getting served by each of the staff.